# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'pollScm' found among steps (Jenkins scripted pipeline)

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to configure scm polling for my scripted jenkins pipeline  with:

```
  properties([
    pipelineTriggers([pollScm('*/5 * * * *')]),
    disableConcurrentBuilds(),
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactNumToKeepStr: '50'))
  ])

  node('builder') {

      stage("Checkout") {
        deleteDir()
        checkout scm

      }

  }
```

but when I run that pipeline I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'pollScm' found among steps [_OcAction, ...
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:203)
```

I have tried with a timetrigger and that works fine:

```
  properties([
    pipelineTriggers([cron('*/5 * * * *')]),
    disableConcurrentBuilds(),
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactNumToKeepStr: '50'))
  ])
```

Why is the `pollScm` trigger not recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typographical error. Instead of `pollScm` it has be `pollSCM`, the last three letters are capitalized. As you can see here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers alternatively available methods are part of the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` expection detail message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'pollScm' found among steps
[archive, ..., plainText, plugin, pollSCM, preserveStashes, ...]
```